# simple protractor test failing with unexpected result

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I am trying to run protractor test agains url http://na5.keylo.co/, target is:

1. fill `_model` field with data 'Oracle Corporation'
2. `click` Search button
3. expect result against search is count 508

spec code:

```
describe('keylocations home page', function () {
it('should search condos', function () {
    browser.get('http://na5.keylo.co/');

    element(by.model('_model')).sendKeys("Oracle Corporation");
    element(by.css('.search__block.search__submit')).click();


    var condos = element.all(by.repeater('condo in scrollResults'));
    expect(condos.count()).toEqual(508);

    // this also can be used to get desired test completed
    //expect(element(by.css('.bar__number'))).toEqual("508 condos found");

});
});
```

Problem :

I always get `0` in `by.repeater` result, whereas I see exact result when I use on browser manually, Its simple but I am making mistake don't know what?

**EDIT:**

Using conf.js as suggested by @Gunderson :

```
//this works and sows success
browser.driver.wait(browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.css('.bar__number')));


//this fails with following error log
expect(element(by.css('.bar__number')).getText()).toEqual("508 condos found");


//this also fails with following error log
browser.driver.wait(expect(element(by.css('.bar__number')).getText()).toEqual("508 condos found"));
```

> Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub [launcher]
>   Running 1 instances of WebDriver Spec started Started WARNING - more
>   than one element found for locator by.model("_model") - the first
>   result will be used
>
> keylocations home page
>       ? should search condos
>         - Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] no injector found for element argument to
>   getTestability\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/ng/test"
>
> F
>
> ---
>
> - Failures                    *
>
>   ---
>
> 1) keylocations home page should search condos
>     - Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] no injector found for element argument to
>   getTestability\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/ng/test"
>
> Executed 1 of 1 spec (1 FAILED) in 14 secs.
>
> Failures: 1) keylocations home page should search condos   Message:
>       Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] no injector found for element argument to
>   getTestability\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/ng/test"   Stack:
>       Error: Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] no injector found for element argument to
>   getTestability\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/ng/te st"
>           at C:\Users\Hair\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:101:16
>           at Promise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\Hair\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1329:14)
>           at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\Hair\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2790:14)
>           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\Hair\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2773:21)
>
> 1 spec, 1 failure Finished in 14.407 seconds [launcher] 0 instance(s)
>   of WebDriver still running [launcher] chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
>   [launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s) [launcher] Process exited with
>   error code 1

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is something wrong with your local settings to me.  I copied your code and it passed (well failed because the number was wrong, but it retrieved the # of condos).

```
describe('keylocations home page', function () {
  it('should search condos', function () {
    browser.get('http://na5.keylo.co/');

    element(by.model('_model')).sendKeys("Oracle Corporation");
    element(by.css('.search__block.search__submit')).click();


    var condos = element.all(by.repeater('condo in scrollResults'));
    expect(condos.count()).toEqual(508);

    // this also can be used to get desired test completed
    //expect(element(by.css('.bar__number'))).toEqual("508 condos found");
  });
});
```

This returns: [image: console]

Seems you have something wrong locally.  I'll paste a link to my config file https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7a682f45999c0377013e409fe6dd4e24 - other than that, I suggest you update Protractor, webDriver, and Jasmine.

I'm on Protractor 2.5.1 and Jasmine 2.3.4.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, if you uncomment `expect(element(by.css('.bar__number'))).toEqual("508 condos found");` test should pass then, do you think so?

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `expect(element(by.css('.bar__number')).getText()).toEqual("508 condos found");` - (added getText) because otherwise you're operating on objects.  But I ran that and the site seems to be slow to respond now, so it's returning an empty string at the moment.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, I can accept it if it works as desired. I am trying to get what is mentioned in OP.

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon check out [this doc](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md)